# How to Control an Animation of 3D Object Using Slider in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

Let's  Say that we have a 3d game object on our scene with single Animation on it so what should i have to do to control its Animation using slider like if change the values of slider the Animation will play according to that values

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have created an animator with their animations.

You only have to know that your callback onValueChanged is called every time you modify the slider value. So there is where you want to set the new animation modes.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI; // Required when Using UI elements.

public class SliderAnimator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Slider mainSlider;
    public Animator anim;
    public void Start()
    {
        //Adds a listener to the main slider and invokes a method when the value changes.
        mainSlider.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate {ValueChangeCheck(); });
    }

    // Invoked when the value of the slider changes.
    public void ValueChangeCheck()
    {           
        //Here we set the animation            
        switch((int)mainSlider.value){
          case 0:
            //Set first animation
            anim.SetBool("FirstAnimationName", true);
            break;
          case 1:
            //Set second animation
            anim.SetBool("SecondAnimationName", true);
            break;
          default:            
            break;
        }

        //To avoid casting the mainSlider.value
        if(mainSlider.value >= 0 && mainSlider.value < 0.5f)
        {
            //Set first animation
            anim.SetBool("FirstAnimationName", true);
        }
        if(mainSlider.value >= 0.5f && mainSlider.value <= 1f)
        {
            //Set second animation
            anim.SetBool("SecondAnimationName", true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where to attach this script with animated object or slider?

Comment: im getting this error A switch expression of type `float' cannot be converted to an integral type, bool, char, string, enum or nullable type

Comment: @NoumanKhan you can attach it where u want, while you put the reference to the slider and the animator. You should cast mainSlider.value to int (like (int)mainSlaider.value, as it is a float value, and switch can't deal with floats. So cast the value, or convert the statement into if's or another conditionals

Comment: @NoumanKhan I've edited the answer as you can see how the cast works, and let the same block made it with if's instead of switch ^^

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want something similar to a VideoPlayer(youtube video player for example) but with animations. Start here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationState-time.html

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

    public class ExampleScript : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Animation anim;
        public float animationTime;// attach your slider value to this float

        void Update()
        {
            anim["Walk"].time = animationTime;
        }
    }
```

Comment: cant understand a single thing haha

Comment: do you want to implement a player like this?
https://sketchfab.com/models/68b406c9784d414f8fe1ad27caf2fc21

Comment: no no look for example we have a cube in the scene with single animation on it now what i want is to play the animation by changing the value of the slider