# Store References to Scene Objects in prefabs?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Look i have a player and enemy in my scene. i am using vector2.movetowards to move my enemy towards my player but my enemy is a prefab so i have to give it a reference of my player in the inspector as a target but when i delete enemy from scene because its a prefab it deletes the reference of the player  what should i do here is my code thanks i just want that how to permanently store the reference of this target in prefab

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class moveTowards : MonoBehaviour
{       
    public Transform target;
    public float speed;

    void Update()
    {
        float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;

        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, step);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several ways to do that, but the typical one is to find the player object, and then store the target position, you can do it like that:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class moveTowards : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Transform target; //now you can make this variable private!


    public float speed;

    //You can call this on Start, or Awake also, but remember to do the singleton player assignation before you call that function!   
    void OnEnable()
    {
      //Way 1 -> Less optimal
      target = GameObject.Find("PlayerObjectName").transform;

      //Way 2 -> Not the best, you need to add a Tag to your player, let's guess that the Tag is called "Player"
      target = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;

      //Way 3 -> My favourite, you need to update your Player prefab (I attached the changes below)
      target = Player.s_Singleton.gameObject.transform;
    }

    void Update()
    {

        float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;


        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, step);
    }
}
```

For Way 3, you need to implement the [singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) on your Player, it should looks like that:

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{

  static public Player s_Singleton;

  private void Awake(){
    s_Singleton = this; //There are better ways to implement the singleton pattern, but there is not the point of your question
  }

}
```

Comment: I don't see why you used OnEnable here. That should be done in the Start or Awake function

Comment: @Lotan what about the " public transform target" should i remove it or keep it

Comment: @Programmer I don't know if he wants to disable and enable the enemy, and makes the same as if I put it on Awake or Start, so extra functionality! BUT I'll update the question with a side note, cause the singleton delcaration should be before.

Comment: @NoumanKhan you can keep the variable if you want, but you don't need to make it public anymore, so I recommend to make it private

Comment: @Lotan thanks lotan this worked for me now if you please tell me that how to instantiate a same gameobject after every 5 seconds

Comment: @NoumanKhan you're welcome, remember to give feedback on your other questions like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53393518/how-to-control-an-animation-of-3d-object-using-slider-in-unity, and mark the answers if they are correct, please.